# Access env variable with space in .htaccess

Tags: linux, .htaccess, ubuntu

I have defined environment variables in /etc/environment and accessing those variables in .htaccess to set environment variables. All the variables are working fine except the one having white space.

Example:

In my /etc/environment

```
export SITE_NAME=Bliss
export SITE_IDENTITY=Bliss Five
```

In .htaccess

`SetEnv SITE_NAME ${SITE_NAME} #This works fine
 SetEnv SITE_IDENTITY ${SITE_IDENTITY} #This variable is causing an error`

Here SITE_IDENTITY variable is causing an error due to the space in variable value.

I have tried following which is not working :

`export SITE_IDENTITY="Bliss Five"
 export SITE_IDENTITY=Bliss\ Five`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue with following changes:

In my /etc/environment I used quotes for variable values having blank space.

`export SITE_NAME=Bliss
 export SITE_IDENTITY="Bliss Five"`

In .htaccess also I used quotes for the variables having blank space

`SetEnv SITE_NAME ${SITE_NAME} #This works fine
 SetEnv SITE_IDENTITY "${SITE_IDENTITY}" #This works fine now`

This resolved my issue. Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you'r using this method, you need to restart apache2 with each change (/etc/environment), because you will need to load /etc/environment in /etc/apache2/envvars, which is load only at start of apache2.

And the string in /etc/environment needs to be quoted.

I would recommend set it just in .htacesss, which is load with each requests usually on webhostings.

On the other hand it have some performance issue when the site get bigger and its better disable loading .htaccess (via AllowOverride None) and set them into vhost configuration via include directly. With this you will need only reload configuration with each change and not restart, which is better than the solution you have.

```
root@frenkye:/home/www/pinkas.it/subdomains/stack$ cat /etc/environment
export SITE_NAME=Bliss
export SITE_IDENTITY="Bliss Five2"
root@frenkye:/home/www/pinkas.it/subdomains/stack$ cat /etc/apache2/envvars
# envvars - default environment variables for apache2ctl
. /etc/environment
```

Comment: Thanks @Jakub, I did restart apache2 several times. Also I tried with the quoted, but, I didn't get any positive results.

Comment: That is weird, I test the settings look: http://stack.pinkas.it/ as you can see in _SERVER variables.